# tableView Cell left side is white

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swift

i've created a tableView where i'm trying to give it a backgroundColor, but suddenly a weird behaviour has occurred. The left side is white instead of the backgroundColor i did give it? What is the reason for this?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#333843")
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 16)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Favoritter"
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(rgba: "#ffef7c")


    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: try to change the inset = 0 or change the cell background color to your current background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying the color background on the text label.

So if you want to change the background of the cell, you should do this :

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#333843")
```

Comment: Did my answer solved the problem? If not you can check your Storyboard or your xib file, the cell maybe not takes all his container size.

Answer (score 0):

Apply background color to contentView.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#333843")
```